# Solr 6.5.1 search in order first full match second left to right match

Tags: solr, lucene

I am using lucene for indexing and solr for searching and having below requirements

example: “Test Five”

1. Highest priority  - Words having both “Test” and “Five”
2. Next -  Words having only left most word “Test”
3. Next – Next word in the list –“Five” (left to right) etc etc

Please find my schema

```
<field name="name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="acSearch" type="searchFieldType" required="false" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />
<copyField source="name" dest="acSearch" />
<fieldType name="searchFieldType" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="[,]+" />
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="25" />
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="[,]+" />
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />

        </analyzer></fieldType>
```

solrconfig.xml

```
 <requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
 <lst name="defaults">
  <str name="wt">json</str>
  <str name="indent">true</str>
  <str name="fl">name</str>
  <str name="rows">200</str>
  <str name="df">dySearch</str>
  <str name="sort">score desc</str>
</lst>
<arr name="components">
  <str>query</str>
</arr>
```

I am not getting proper out put if i search

1.Test Five in response Test Five is coming first next not from left to right in any order data is coming

2. If i search Five Test related data is coming first .

Please could you help ....

Comment: Please could some one help to resolve above problem

Answer (score 2):

you can just give a different boost to each of the terms when you build your query string:

```
 q=Test^10 Five^3 last^1
```

With this, you don't need to mess with ngram etc, use just some standard analyzer